# What is best way to restrict guest user to access administrative functionality in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp

I'd like to hide/remove functionalities such as run, cmd, regedit and etc (administrative features) from a particular user in Windows XP. I tried to do group policy but I was not able to locate users tab when I attempted to set it up. Is there any other ways to achieve such goal?

Comment: Group policy is it, maybe you should try and figure out why you couldn't find your users tab. What method were you using? gpedit?

Comment: **I tried to do group policy but I was not able to locate users tab when I attempted to set it up** - What user tab are you referring to?

Comment: users tab which you should be able to locate at browse on select group policy object

Comment: @AthomSfere I tried but I couldn't find any solution for that.. I used mmc to create group local policy.

Comment: Go under USERS(in control panel) and create a **Standard User** this will significantly restrict them.

Answer (score 0):

remove administrator privileges from the guest account under account management? i didnt think guest accounts EVER got access to administrative functions, but i dont know if youre talking about the actual 'guest' login or you have a guest in your local area using your machine. either way you probably want to edit the settings under 'account management' or whatever they call it